# как можно сократить этот код?

Tags: javascript

```
let profile = message.text;
if (/^(фундаментальная информатика и информационные технологии|профиль 1)$/i.test(profile)) number = 1;
if (/^(строительство|профиль 2)$/i.test(profile)) number = 2;
if (/^(инженер по оборудованию|профиль 3)$/i.test(profile)) number = 3
if (/^(инспектор по технике безопасности|профиль 4)$/i.test(profile)) number = 4;
if (/^(бухгалтерский учёт, анализ и аудит|профиль 5)$/i.test(profile)) number = 5;
if (/^(продавец, контролёр-кассир|профиль 6)$/i.test(profile)) number = 6;
if (/^(современная фотография|профиль 7)$/i.test(profile)) number = 7;
if (/^(звукорежиссура аудиовизуальных искусств|профиль 8)$/i.test(profile)) number = 8;
```

Comment: полагаю тут и регулярка не нужна.

Comment: она, чтобы от регистра не зависело

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое сделать **[карту](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)**

```js
const kvArray = [
  ['(фундаментальная информатика и информационные технологии|профиль 1)', 1], 
  ['(строительство|профиль 2)', 2],
  ['(инженер по оборудованию|профиль 3)', 3],
  // и так далее
]
const myMap = new Map(kvArray);
let profile = '(СТроиТельство|ПРОФиль 2)';

console.log(myMap.get(profile.toLowerCase()));
```

---

Если цифры по порядку, то можно даже в простой массив записать и использовать **[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)** + 1

```js
const kvArray = [
  ['(фундаментальная информатика и информационные технологии|профиль 1)'],
  ['(строительство|профиль 2)'],
  ['(инженер по оборудованию|профиль 3)'],
  // и так далее
]

let profile = '(СТроиТельство|ПРОФиль 2)';
let number = kvArray.findIndex(el => el == profile.toLowerCase()) + 1;
console.log(number);
```

Comment: большое спасибо! я думал воспользоваться findIndex, но она не работает с регуляркой. идея с toLowerCase() крутая

Comment: Просто тут регулярка и не нужна

Answer (score 0):

Ну если строки только такие, то можно

```
let profile = message.text;
let number = profile[profile.length-2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let profile = message.text;
let find = profile.match(/\s(\d+)\)$/);
let number = find ? find[1] : undefined;
```